# Can't filter Oracle SELECT in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, oracle, ora-01722

Part of an ASP.Net 2 datasource:

```
  SelectCommand="SELECT BU.P_GEAC_CORP_CD AS Corp_Code,
                        BU.Business_unit  as Abbreviation,
                        CC.DEPTID         AS Cost_Center,
                        CC.DESCR          AS Description
                 FROM fstst.PS_P_CATR_BUDPT_VW CC,
                      fstst.ps_p_bus_unit_cnv  BU 
                 WHERE BU.Business_unit = CC.Business_unit">
```

This feeds a GridView which works.  The display shows that

```
CC.DESCR          AS Description
```

is text (non-numeric).

I want to use a textbox as a "contains" filter, i.e., if I put "Recovery" in the box,
I want the datasource to add

```
AND CC.DESCR Like '%Recovery%'
```

to the SQL.  If I hard-code that line, it works.

But if I add

```
 <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Dept_Name"
                          Name="DName"
                          PropertyName="Text"
                          Type="string" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

**without** changing the SQL, I get **no** rows returned.  Then if I put

```
AND CC.DESCR Like '%' + :DName + '%'
```

into the SQL, I get no results when the textbox is blank, and ORA-01722: invalid number as soon as I put characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the attempt, "birdlips."

Unfortunately, the Oracle server had only minimal logging turned on.

On top of that, while I was visiting the DBA, stackoverflow somehow ended up on our company's list of forbidden sites.  So I could not share the answer.

This must be a little known fact about Oracle, as our two DBAs didn't catch it either: Oracle thinks **plus** is for numbers no matter what the context.

It worked as soon as I changed **+** to **||**

Comment: `||` is actually the ANSI standard string concatenation operator, so it's not uncommon to find that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use single quotes around the text when using a like statement with a string.

It needs to look like

```
AND CC_DESCR LIKE '%VALUE%'
```

Comment: Thanks, but the single quotes _are_ there in
AND CC.DESCR Like '%' + :DName + '%'
and by the way,
AND CC.DESCR Like '%:DName%'
gets the same result

Comment: If you mean the SQL, it's in the question.
If you mean something else, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I would like to see your SQL output as it is ran in ORACLE not how you have it coded.  I want the runtime SQL.

Comment: I do not know how to put parameterized ASP.Net SQL into an SQLPlus prompt.

Comment: if you have a debugger you should be able to get it.  Also, check your logs and you might get lucky and see the output there.

Comment: Unfortunately, the debugger does not allow stepping into the Oracle interface code.  However, I will visit the DBA and see whether anything is in the log.  Thanks

Comment: for sure, sorry I can't be of more help.  Seeing the runtime SQL might be the key to resolving this for you, unless someone else answers.